Any method to limit a cross-node RDMA-based program's maximum usable IB bandwidth?
I want to test a RDMA-based program's inter-node performance under a limited IB bandwidth. But I don't have sudo permission, no container software. Is there any alternative method can achieve this goal? For instance, when I run this RDMA-based parogram, running another IB traffic injection software at the same time?
Thanks!
I searched online with any recommended method, but all of the solutions are related to modify ofed driver's qos setting, where needs sodo permission and machine restart.
I would expect any suggestions in no-root manner.
